# Single Sign On with Active Directory Using LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get user information from LDAP function. I need a single sign in for my PHP application on Active Directory. I am using following function:

```
$ldapserver = 'abc.com';
$ldapuser      = 'ali@abc.com'; 
$ldappass     = 'xyz';
$attributes_ad = array
("displayName","description","cn","givenName","sn","mail","co","mobile","company","
displayName");
// define base
$base ="";
// connect
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
if($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to
bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...<br /><br />";
        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $base, "mail=$email*", $attributes_ad) or die ("Error in search
        query");
                                $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
             //Now, to display the results we want:
                for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
                                {
                                // to show the attribute displayName (note the case!)
                                echo $info[$i]["displayname"][0];
                                }
                }
}
```

Above code requires username and password both but I need a solution that can get the username and password whenever someone will login with AD credentials I need to use them to authenticate my login for my PHP application (actually it is an intranet application). Please help me with that I need to fetch all available user info from active directory.

Comment: So when I get you right, you want a user - that is already logged into the computer - to access a website and be logged in with their credentials from the computer login. No further username or password is required.

What usually uses kerberos and needs a kerberised webserver as the webserver needs to pass the information about the kerberos ticket to PHP. So it depends on whether you are running on Apache or IIS or nginx or... Can you give us some more details on those technical details?

Comment: BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856828/php-ldap-function-and-active-directory-intigrations-for-single-signin is exactly the same question. I don't think you will get more more answers by posting multiple times.

Comment: @heiglandreas The Link provided by you is broken.

Comment: Looks like the OP removed the other question… ;-) I'll shortly remove the comment then…